# Why the ld crash in building libgd?

Tags: linker, gd, solaris, ld

I try to build [libgd](https://bitbucket.org/libgd/gd-libgd/downloads) on my `Solaris` 10 (x86). In link stage, there is a core dump:

```
libtool: link: gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -Wl,-z -Wl,text -Wl,-h -Wl,libgd.so.3 -o .libs/libgd.so.3.0.0  .libs/gd.o .libs/gd_color.o .libs/gd_color_map.o .libs/gd_transform.o .libs/gdfx.o .libs/gd_security.o .libs/gd_gd.o .libs/gd_gd2.o .libs/gd_io.o .libs/gd_io_dp.o .libs/gd_gif_in.o .libs/gd_gif_out.o .libs/gd_io_file.o .libs/gd_io_ss.o .libs/gd_jpeg.o .libs/gd_png.o .libs/gd_ss.o .libs/gd_topal.o .libs/gd_wbmp.o .libs/gdcache.o .libs/gdfontg.o .libs/gdfontl.o .libs/gdfontmb.o .libs/gdfonts.o .libs/gdfontt.o .libs/gdft.o .libs/gdhelpers.o .libs/gdkanji.o .libs/gdtables.o .libs/gdxpm.o .libs/wbmp.o .libs/gd_filter.o .libs/gd_nnquant.o .libs/gd_rotate.o .libs/gd_matrix.o .libs/gd_interpolation.o .libs/gd_crop.o .libs/webpimg.o .libs/gd_webp.o .libs/gd_tiff.o .libs/gd_tga.o .libs/gd_bmp.o .libs/gd_xbm.o .libs/gd_color_match.o   -R/usr/local/lib -R/usr/local/lib -R/usr/sfw/lib -R/usr/local/ssl/lib -R/usr/openwin/lib -R/usr/lib -R/usr/X11R6/lib -R/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.7/lib -R/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.2/lib -L/usr/openwin/lib -L/usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so -lz -lm /usr/local/lib/libpng12.so -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.7/lib -L/usr/sfw/lib /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.so /usr/local/lib/libfontconfig.so -L/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.2/lib -lc
collect2: ld terminated with signal 8 [Arithmetic Exception], core dumped
make[2]: *** [libgd.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/data1/nan/libgd-2.1.0/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/data1/nan/libgd-2.1.0/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I use `gdb` to analyze the core dump:

```
Core was generated by `/usr/ccs/bin/ld -G -dy -z text -R/usr/local/lib -R/usr/local/lib -R/usr/sfw/lib'.
Program terminated with signal 8, Arithmetic exception.
[New process 92717    ]
#0  0xfeedd80c in process_cap () from /lib/libld.so.4
(gdb) bt
#0  0xfeedd80c in process_cap () from /lib/libld.so.4
#1  0xfeee002a in process_elf () from /lib/libld.so.4
#2  0xfeee0663 in ld32_process_ifl () from /lib/libld.so.4
#3  0xfeee0aa8 in ld32_process_open () from /lib/libld.so.4
#4  0xfeed9557 in process_files_com () from /lib/libld.so.4
#5  0xfeed96a4 in ld32_process_files () from /lib/libld.so.4
#6  0xfeedb58b in ld32_main () from /lib/libld.so.4
#7  0x08051a82 in main ()
```

From `gdb`, I can see the core occurs at 0xfeedd80c:

```
0xfeedd80c <process_cap+64>:    div    %esi
(gdb) i registers esi
esi            0x0      0
```

I can see the cause is dividing zero. But because I don't have the source code of `ld`, I can't analyse deeper. Could anyone give some clues on this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure libm.so is the file being processed when the problem is
encountered?  libm.so is a system library, and it's .SUNW_cap looks
fine (which is what I'd expect).

Oh wait, try 'LD_OPTIONS=-Dfiles,cap,details'.  Perhaps the 'cap'
alone is telling you information in regards the last file where the
capabilities were processed.  'file' will tell you which file ld(1)
is presently working on.

And, a colleague just reminded me - capabilities sections can be created
using the Solaris link-editor, but if you take a relocatable object
with capabilities and reprocess it with gld (or perhaps objcopy?) you
might get an "invalid" capabilities section:

```
% elfdump -H foo.o
...
Object Capabilities:
    index  tag           value
      [0]  CA_SUNW_HW_1  0x800  [ SSE ]

% gld -r foo.o -o bar.o
% elfdump -H bar.o
bar.o: .SUNW_cap: zero sh_entsize information, expected 0x8
```

Regardless, ld(1) shouldn't be falling over.  I'll get that addressed.

Comment: After using "`LD_OPTIONS=-Dfiles`", I find the root cause, not libm, but another library. Thanks! BTW, it should be "`LD_OPTIONS=-Ddetail`", not `details`. Please using "`ld -Dhelp`" check.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting '`LD_OPTIONS=-Dcap,details`' and execute the link stage.

This should identify the file that is contributing the capabilities that are causing the issue.  Inspect this input file with '`elfdump -H`'.

If you can determine the questionable input file, also look at the capabilities section:

```
% elfdump -cN.SUNW_cap foo.o

Section Header[1]:  sh_name: .SUNW_cap
    sh_addr:      0xf4            sh_flags:   [ SHF_ALLOC SHF_INFO_LINK ]
    sh_size:      0xf8            sh_type:    [ SHT_SUNW_cap ]
    sh_offset:    0xf4            sh_entsize: 0x8 (31 entries)
```

Is it possible that the sh_entsize value is 0?

Comment: After executing the command, the output is `bash-3.2# elfdump -cN.SUNW_cap /usr/lib/libm.so

Section Header[1]:  sh_name: .SUNW_cap
    sh_addr:      0xb4            sh_flags:   [ SHF_ALLOC ]
    sh_size:      0x10            sh_type:    [ SHT_SUNW_cap ]
    sh_offset:    0xb4            sh_entsize: 0x8 (2 entries)
    sh_link:      0               sh_info:    0
    sh_addralign: 0x4`

What can we learn from this information?